# Spring request mapping in jquery grid

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, jqgrid

i want to invoke method in POJO class in jquery grid script .

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({

    datatype: "json",
    url:"/showStudent.do",
    type:"",
    colNames:['Student Name','Age', 'Mobile'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'name',index:'id', width:55,formatter:custom_func},
        {name:'age', width:90},
        {name:'mobile', width:100},
        ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],

    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"Student List"
});
```

so above by default look for get method but the destination class doesn't have that

```
@RequestMapping("/showStudent.do")
public String showEnrolledStudent(Model model)
{
    PersistenceManager pm=PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Query query=pm.newQuery(Student.class);
    JSONArray studentListJson=new JSONArray();
    try
    {
        List<Student> listOfStudent=(List<Student>) query.execute(); 
        for(Student student:listOfStudent)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("name", student.getName());
            jsonObject.put("age", student.getAge());
            jsonObject.put("mobile", student.getMobile());
            studentListJson.put(jsonObject);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
    System.out.println("hi");
    System.out.println(studentListJson);
    return studentListJson.toString();
}
```

So how can make binding between jquery grid url call to showEnrolledStudent() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for mapping method with Http get request and http Post request method property of request mapping annotation is used

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="/showStudent.do")
@ResponseBody
public String showEnrolledStudent()
{
    //This will get persistence manager for datastore interaction
    PersistenceManager pm=PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    //Query for selecting list of student enrolled
    Query query=pm.newQuery(Student.class);
    //Json array holds the json objects.
    JSONArray studentListJson=new JSONArray();
    try
    {
        List<Student> listOfStudent=(List<Student>) query.execute();
        //Loop to create the list of student in json format
        for(Student student:listOfStudent)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("key", student.getKey().getId());
            jsonObject.put("name", student.getName());
            jsonObject.put("age", student.getAge());
            jsonObject.put("mobile", student.getMobile());
            studentListJson.put(jsonObject);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
        return studentListJson.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return JSON as is, you should use [@ResponseBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody) annotation. Otherwise `DispatcherServlet` will try to recognize `View`, and he can't do that.

```
@RequestMapping("/showStudent.do")
@ResponseBody
public String showEnrolledStudent(Model model){
...
```